# Why linux doesn't support different software versions at the same time?

Tags: linux, packaging

We can take **any** programming language, it has package manager that can install **lib-v1** for **program1** and **lib-v2** for **program2**.

When new version of lib is released on linux you can't predict what of your programs will break after update. Let me remind, linux is popular on servers where stability has the highest priority.

For example, many programs were broken by major release of openssh.

So, why? Every programming language can afford such feature, and linux can't?

Comment: Linux is not a programming language, so no, it cannot afford this feature.

Comment: Actually, you can. Take a look at [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) and [Guix](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/).

Comment: BSDs, OS X and Solaris support versioning and side-by-side installations out of the box. Linux is lame and pushes its technological debt onto users. That is, you have to do extra work to get what the other OSes provide. A big part of it is linking and "install names". Linux feels the dominant use case is compile and link against on set of headers and libraries, and then use the wrong library at runtime (yep, you can't make this stuff up...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Linux doesn't support different software versions at the same time?

It's not true. For example [NixOS](https://nixos.org/) and [Guix](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/) support multiple packages versions.

If you ask why Debian or RedHat does not support multiple software version then I'd say it's because of its legacy. In the early days of Linux era, disk space was expensive so it shared libs was the way to reduce required space. Windows has the same problem aka [DLL hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).

> Every programming language can afford such feature, and Linux can't?

It's not true. For example in java, you have [JAR hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell) and can use the only single version of your dependency. I'm not sure if you can find the language where you can use multiple versions of the same lib at once. You can do it, but it's not supported by default. E.g., in Java you can repackage your dependency to a different name.

Comment: I'm reading article about NixOS and it sounds like distro that I was waiting for so many years! Incredible